# Scroll to bottom not working in IE and Edge only when scrolled to top

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I have a script that, after adding content to a div, scrolls its containing div, `<div id="scroll">` to the bottom. The code to do that is:

```
var scroll=document.getElementById("scroll");
/*...add content...*/
if(scroll && scroll.scrollHeight) {
    if(scroll.scroll) {
        scroll.scroll(0,scroll.scrollHeight);
    }
    else if (scroll.scrollTop&&scroll.clientHeight) {
        scroll.scrollTop=scroll.scrollHeight-scroll.clientHeight;
    }
}
```

This works in all browsers that I've tested it in, except in Internet Explorer and Edge when the div is scrolled to the top. It works in Firefox and Google Chrome no matter where the div is scrolled to, but in Internet Explorer and Edge, it only works if it's scrolled below the top first.

Note: I'm not using JQuery or any other library.

Edit: Minimal document test case

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Minimal Scroll Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="scroll" style="height:5em;max-height:5em;overflow:auto;"><div id="text"> </div></div>
<button onClick="add_text();">add text</button>
<script>
var i=1;
function add_text()
{
    var text=document.getElementById("text");
    var scroll=document.getElementById("scroll");
    text.innerHTML+="Text"+i+"<br /> ";
    i++;
    if(scroll && scroll.scrollHeight) {
        if(scroll.scroll) {
            scroll.scroll(0,scroll.scrollHeight);
        }
        else if (scroll.scrollTop&&scroll.clientHeight) {
            scroll.scrollTop=scroll.scrollHeight-scroll.clientHeight;
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `scroll()` is not yet supported on Internet Explorer and Edge. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll

Comment: @Addis That shouldn't matter because I'm using `scrollTop` as a fallback and it works if the element is scrolled(it only fails if the element is scrolled to the very top).

Comment: Please post a minimal code enough to replicate the problem so that it becomes easier to help. I can see the fallback indeed.

Comment: @Addis I've added enough code to paste into an HTML document. It works in Google Chrome and Firefox, but in IE, it only works if you scroll down a little bit(maybe to where `Text2` is added).

Comment: I couldn't get what you're trying to accomplish and what the problem is. The program behaves the same both in Chrome and Edge. And in my test, none of the conditional statements get executed.

Comment: Besides, `scroll.scroll` doesn't seem appropriate, as scroll is a method not a property you should use it like `scroll.scroll()` and then it wouldn't make sense inside the if condition.

Comment: @Addis The `if(scroll.scroll)` is to detect whether or not the `scroll()` method exists. In Internet Explorer(and Edge in my full case), it works the same as in Chrome but only if the div is not scrolled to the top. If the div is scrolled to the top, it stays scrolled to the top.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the if condition, we could compare the div's scrollHeight and clientHeight property to detect whether the div has a vertical scroll bar. If the value of scrollHeight more than the clientHeight value, the div will have a vertical scroll bar.

Try to modify your code as below:

```
<div id="scroll" style="height:5em;max-height:5em;overflow:auto;"><div id="text"> </div></div>
<button onClick="add_text();">add text</button>
<script>
    var i = 1;
    function add_text() {
        var text = document.getElementById("text");
        var scroll = document.getElementById("scroll");
        text.innerHTML += "Text" + i + "<br /> ";
        i++;
        if (scroll.scrollHeight > scroll.clientHeight) { 
            scroll.scrollTop = scroll.scrollHeight; 
        }
    }
</script>
```

The result in Edge browser as below:

[image]

IE browser:

[image]